# Error with conflicting types in calculator (division)

Tags: c

I'm building a calculator for my first project in C and everything worked fine until I implemented division. It keeps giving me the error "conflicting types for `div`", even though the function is exactly the same as all the others.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int num1;
int num2;
char op;
int res;
int poscount;
int negcount;

int add(num1, num2) {
    res = num1 + num2;
    printf("Result: %d\n", res);
    if(res >= 0)
        poscount += 1;
    else
        negcount += 1;
    return res;
}
int sub(num1, num2) {
    res = num1 - num2;
    printf("Result: %d\n", res);
    if(res >= 0)
        poscount += 1;
    else
        negcount += 1;
    return res;
}
int mul(num1, num2){
    res = num1 * num2;
    printf("Result: %d\n", res);
    if(res >= 0)
        poscount += 1;
    else
        negcount += 1;
    return res;
}
int div(num1, num2) {
    res = num1 / num2;
    printf("Result: %d\n", res)
    return res;
}
int main() {

    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);    //Zahl 1
    while(op != '=') {
        printf("\nOperator: ");
        scanf(" %c", &op);       //Operator
        if (op == '=') {         //Überprüfung ob User weiterrechnen will
            printf("Final result: %d\n", res);
            printf("Number of positive: %d\n", poscount);
            printf("Number of negatives: %d\n", negcount);
            break;
        }
        printf("\nNumber: ");
        scanf("%d", &num2);    //Zahl

        if(op == '+') {
            num1 = add(num1, num2);  //Addition
        }
        else if(op == '-'){
            num1 = sub(num1, num2); //Subtraktion
        }
        else if(op == '*'){
            num1 = mul(num1, num2); //Multiplikation
        }
        else if(op == '/'){         //Divisionen
            if(num2 == 0) {
                printf("Division by 0.");  //Ausnahme Division durch 0
                printf("No new result.");
            }
            else {
                num1 = div(num1, num2);
            }
        else {
            printf("Unknown operator");
        }
        }
return 0;
}
```

That's my code. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a name conflict.  Look at the man page for `div`.  It's a library function, declared in `stdlib.h`.  You can't redefine it with an incompatible declaration without conflicting with `stdlib.h`.  The simplest solution is to just use a different name.

Comment: Avoid using globals.

Comment: Your code is using old-fashioned implicit `int` for your argument types. You need to take a couple of steps back, review your beginners books (assuming they're written the last 20 years or so) or get newer books.

Comment: Also recommend adding `int` to parameters in function definitions.  It may not be required, since they will default to `int`, but it is a good practice to be explicit.

Comment: Implicit int was removed from the language in C99.   That's over 20 years ago (give or take, depending on ... so many things).  Don't use it.

Comment: use a newer book [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `div` has the same name as the [C standard library function `div`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/div). The latter returns a value of the type `div_t`, and not an `int`, hence the error reporting "conflicting types".

The solution, and a good general practice, is to not have a function with the same name as one from the C standard library. Here, for example, name your function `myDiv`. I understand that this is an exercise in programming; otherwise you would want to *use* the standard library functions instead of reimplementing them.

*Some additional advice*:

- Do not use global variables if their use can reasonably be avoided. This is the case here. In addition to that, do not reuse the variable names within functions (this is called *shadowing*).
- Initialize `poscount` and `negcount` to 0.
- Initialize `op` to some placeholder value (here, not `=`). Better yet, restructure the code so that `op` is assigned from the input first and evaluated afterwards.
- Do not rely on the default type of variables being `int`, but declare the type explicitly.
- The variable 'res' appears to be unused. Isn't the result stored in `num1`?
- Use the pre-increment operator (`++` before the variable name) instead of `+= 1`.
- Use a switch-statement instead of multiple else-if's.
- Using English comments will make your code more easily understood by a wider audience.

*Working code with some (not all) fixes applied:*

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int poscount = 0;
int negcount = 0;

int add(int num1, int num2) {
    int res = num1 + num2;
    printf("Result: %d\n", res);
    if (res >= 0)
        ++poscount;
    else
        ++negcount;
    return res;
}

int sub(int num1, int num2) {
    int res = num1 - num2;
    printf("Result: %d\n", res);
    if (res >= 0)
        ++poscount;
    else
        ++negcount;
    return res;
}

int mul(int num1, int num2){
    int res = num1 * num2;
    printf("Result: %d\n", res);
    if (res >= 0)
        ++poscount;
    else
        ++negcount;
    return res;
}

int myDiv(int num1, int num2) {
    int res = num1 / num2;
    printf("Result: %d\n", res);
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int num1;
    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);    //Zahl 1

    char op = 'X'; // placeholder value
    while (op != '=') {
        printf("\nOperator: ");
        scanf(" %c", &op);       //Operator
        if (op == '=') {         //Überprüfung ob User weiterrechnen will
            printf("Final result: %d\n", num1);
            printf("Number of positive: %d\n", poscount);
            printf("Number of negatives: %d\n", negcount);
            break;
        }
        printf("\nNumber: ");
        int num2;
        scanf("%d", &num2);    //Zahl

        if (op == '+') {
            num1 = add(num1, num2);  //Addition
        }
        else if (op == '-'){
            num1 = sub(num1, num2); //Subtraktion
        }
        else if (op == '*'){
            num1 = mul(num1, num2); //Multiplikation
        }
        else if (op == '/'){         //Divisionen
            if (num2 == 0) {
                printf("Division by 0.");  //Ausnahme Division durch 0
                printf("No new result.");
            }
            else {
                num1 = myDiv(num1, num2);
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Unknown operator");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```